# X, Y-components of the spin density operator always equal to 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, many-body

In the second quantization formalism spin density operator is defined in the following way:
$$\hat{\mathbf{S}}(x) = \frac{\hbar}{2}\sum\limits_{\sigma, \sigma'}\hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}_{\sigma}(x)\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{\sigma,\sigma'}\hat{\Psi}_{\sigma'}(x)$$
where $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is a vector of Pauli matrices.
Field operators can be expanded in the single particle basis:
$$\hat{\Psi}_{\sigma}(x) = \sum\limits_{k}\hat{a}_{k,\sigma}\phi_{k,\sigma}(x)$$
Typically $\phi_{k,\sigma}(x) = \phi_{k}(x)\chi_{\sigma}$ and $\chi_{\sigma}^{*}\chi_{\sigma'} = \delta_{\sigma, \sigma'}$.

Does this mean that always $\hat{S}_x(x) = \hat{S}_y(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\chi^*_\sigma \, \boldsymbol{\sigma}_{\sigma,\sigma'} \chi_{\sigma'} \neq \chi^*_\sigma \chi_{\sigma'} \, \boldsymbol{\sigma}_{\sigma,\sigma'}$. You cannot pull $\chi$ through $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$, since they live in the same space and "don't commute". Not that it would make sense either, since $\chi$ is a state vector in spin space and $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is a operator in spin space, so pulling through like that gives you a number on one side and a operator on the other.

Comment: Yep, you are right!